# How can you determine if a bar will tilt with 2 points of rotation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, angular-momentum, torque

Say we have the typical press machine in the gym to exercise your chest, it is usually helped with 2 points of contact and weights on the sides of the points of contact:

[image: Drawing]

(Sorry for the quality) How would one determine if the bar along with the red weights are going to tilt to one side? Obviously assuming that the weights on one side must be greater than on the other for the bar to tilt and assuming that the bar is symmetrical.

I thought that it had to do with some easy torque or angular momentun manipulations but I think it can get a little bit harder than that

Comment: just easy torque is enough

Comment: To make sure I undestand, are you asking how much unbalanced weight would cause the barbell to fall off the rails?

Comment: @MarkH yes, precisely, and how I would find that

Comment: Hint: You write the force/torque balance equations, and when one of the support forces goes to zero or negative, the bar will tilt to the other side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the diagram below distance are $a,\,b\,c$ and $d$ and masses are shown as $M_{\rm xxx}$ and $M_{\rm xxx}$ which if multiplied by $g$, the gravitational field strength, will be the values of the forces, for brevity.

[image]

Looking at your diagram it would seem that it is highly unlikely that the bar will tip unless there is a large disparity between the masses.

If the right-hand end is to move up then $N_{\rm right}$ would become zero and

$M_{\rm left}$ would have to be greater than $\dfrac{b\, M_{\rm bar} +(b+c+d)\,M_{\rm right}}{a}$ which is obtained by taking moments about the left-hand support.

If the left-hand end is to move up then $N_{\rm left}$ would become zero and

$M_{\rm right}$ would have to be greater than $\dfrac{c\, M_{\rm bar} +(a+b+c)\,M_{\rm left}}{d}$ which is obtained by taking moments about the right-hand support.

——

Explanation

For moment read torque.  About the left hand support the counterclockwise torque is $M_{\rm left }\times a + N_{\rm right}\times (b+c)$ and the clockwise torque is $c\times  M_{\rm bar} +(a+b+c)\times M_{\rm right}$.
For equilibrium the magnitude of these two torques is the same.
As $M_{\rm left }$ gets bigger $N_{\rm right}$ gets smaller until it will become zero.
In that condition the value of $M_{\rm left }$ is the maximum it can be and any further increase in $M_{\rm left }$ will cause the bar to tilt.

Comment: can you expand a little bit on how you obtain these expressions? Like taking the angular momentum to be 0? Or the torque to be 0? Or how?

Comment: @Ulshy I have added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: Are you sure the clockwise torque is $cM_{bar}+(a+b+c)M_{left}$? Shouldn't it be $bM_{bar}+M_{right}(b+c+d)$? Also why are you writing it as if $M_{xxx}$ was the weight and not the mass? The torque is $r\times F$ not times the mass.

Comment: I have corrected the typos.  Right at the start Iof my answer I pointed out that I have missed out the factor $g$ for brevity.

Comment: Are you sure it is $M_{right} (a+b+c)$ and not $M_{right}(b+c+d)$?

Answer (score 1):

Given such schematics :
[image]

bar will tilt if torques are out of equilibrium (bar weight alone also counts) :

$$ W_1 L_{_{W_1}} + W_{_{B_1}} L_{_{B_1}} \neq W_2 L_{_{W_2}} + W_{_{B_2}} L_{_{B_2}} \tag 1$$

Where:

- $W_1, W_2$ left/right side weights
- $W_{_{B_1}}, W_{_{B_2}}$ weight of left/right bar sides (without disks) as if it would be divided into parts by a pivot point.
- $L_{_{W_1}}, L_{_{W_2}}$ distances from weights to the pivot point
- $L_{_{B_1}}, L_{_{B_2}}$ distances from left/right bar parts COM till the pivot point. (COM points $B_1, B_2$ of bar sides again should be find-out without disks added).

Eq (1) is given in ideal situation where your pair of hands will grab/push bar at the **same time** AND with **same force**. Which in real life may not be accomplished, due to many reasons, such as: your one hand is stronger, stationary bar is already tilted in relation to the ground by some minuscule degree, your brain sends a signal to push bar to one hand a little bit faster than to the other, and many other natural reasons. So, while pushing forward a bar with disks, some (micro-)tilting oscillations should be expected.